# Create new entry from related Entry field

Tags: relations, entry

It would be really nice to create a new entry in a section (say "Dates"-channel) direct from a related entries field in another section (say "Events"-channel). Is this possible already, or are there any plugins for this?

I have asked this before on Google+, but not sure if it's been answered.

Answer (score 4):

Not sure when this was added, but this is now available in Craft core. The select modal has a button to create a new entry of that type.

Comment: It was added in [build 2750](https://craftcms.com/changelog#build2750), December 1st 2015 – the initial Craft 2.5 release.

Answer (score 3):

I personally don't know a plugin that can achieve this as it's not built in the core functionality of Craft.

But there is however a plugin called **[ManyToMany](https://github.com/page-8/craft-manytomany/)**, which allows you to see entries that are related to one-and-other from both ends of the relationship.

I haven't used the plugin myself, and I don't believe you can create entries through it, but it could put you one step closer to the functionality you need.

Comment: Thanks for answering. I'm familiar with this plugin, but it doesn't really solve my problem. I've managed to do this sort of thing front-end with some ajax to retrieve the entry ID of the newly created entry, but don't know how to make plugins. I think it's possible.

Comment: Sure, no problem. As I say I knew this wouldn't solve the issue you were having, but no-one had answered in a while so I thought I'd give you something to try out in the meantime.

Comment: Hi - I developed the Many to Many plugin. If I understand you correctly, it's worth noting that this kind of is the intended workflow of using this plugin. Say, you create an event that has many dates which are in a related section. You would add your event, jump over to the dates channel and and keep adding dates with the associated event. Is there any reason you need to stay in the specific event to add the associated dates? Also, something to consider is if the Dates channel needs to be a full fledged section -- is what you're trying to achieve possible with a matrix for instance?